# How do I implement checkbox select functionality to send emails using ajax/json? If possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have an MVC application that's using dataTables and calling the column's data and checkbox through c# controller and then json/ajax scripts within the .cshtml table index. This probably isn't the most efficient way but it's how I've gotten it to work so far.

If it's possible within the json/ajax or jquery/javascript, how do I go about selecting a checkbox then click a button that calls a modal to send an email but is calling the IDs of the emails within the datatable from the check-boxes so I don't have to manually type in the email addresses that the emails are being sent to (just subject and email body). If it isn't possible, how should I go about it?

html for columns

```
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto" class="tablecontainer">
<a class="popup btn btn-primary" href="/CRUD/save/0" style="margin- 
bottom:20px; margin-top:20px;">Add New Volunteer</a>
<table id="myDatatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"></th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Zip Code</th>
<th>Credentials</th>
<th>Availability</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>

</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

ajax/json example

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
"ajax": {
"url": '/CRUD/GetEmployees',
"type": "get",
"datatype": "json"
},

"columns":
[
{"data": "empty"},
{ "data": "EmailID", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "Password", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "FirstName", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "LastName", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "PhoneNumber", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "UserAddress", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "UserCity", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "UserState", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "UserZip", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "UserCredentials", "autoWidth": true },
{ "data": "UserDate", "autoWidth": true },
{"data": "UserID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
return '<a class="popup" href="/CRUD/save/'+ data + '">Edit</a>';}
},
{
"data": "UserID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
return '<a class="popup" href="/CRUD/delete/' + data + '">Delete</a>';
}}],
'columnDefs': [{
'targets': 0,
'searchable': false,
'orderable': false,
'className': 'dt-body-center',
'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + 
$('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';}}]})

// more code here for modal on clicks for edit and delete views //

</script>
```

Here's a photo example of what it should look like. I have the data table, i just need the button on click functionality and modal.
[image: like this]

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use-

> table.rows('.selected').data()

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var emailbox=$("#emailBox");
  emailbox.val('');
  console.log(table.rows('.selected').data());
  var selectedData=table.rows('.selected').data();
  var emails = $.map(selectedData, function (item) { return item[2] });
  console.log(emails);
  for(var i=0;i<emails.length;i++){
         if(i==0){
             emailbox.val(v);
         }
         else{
           emailbox.val(emailbox.val()+";"+ v);
         }
  }
  $.each(emails,function(k,v){
        emailbox.val(emailbox.val()+v);
  })
```

you can see a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/68wLeya1/8/).